# Drupal 7 breadcrumb not showing

Tags: drupal-7, breadcrumbs

I'm working on a website in Drupal. I activated the breadcrumb default module and configurated it to show breadcrumb  for all pages. I tried to display it into the page with code `<?php print theme('breadcrumb', drupal_get_breadcrumb()); ?>` but it doesn't appear.

I tried also to install path_breadcrumb module, configure it, but also this not showing.

Can someone can help me to understand why it doesn't showed?

Comment: Do you have custom template for page tested ? check on hook_preprocess(&$page) if you have breadcrumb key into $page

Comment: Hi @Fky, thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I work on a custom template but in the directory template, there is the only index.php page, no other page like page.tpl.php. In page.tpl.php on "modules/system/page.tpl.php" there is the hook breadcrumbs

For the administration area, I use Bartik theme and also here breadcrumbs is not showing

Comment: SOLVED: The problem was caused by other modules of breadcrumb installed. I didn't know it because the project was built by other people and there are many things that I don't know about it and I don't know yet very well Drupal structure